# Increase UIAlertView size on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, xcode4.2, uialertview

I am trying to make a iPad application which information will popup inside the UINotification. But the default size of the notification is relatively small. Is there any way i can increase the size of the notification?

```
-(IBAction) player1:(id)sender{

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Player1" message:@"Long message"delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Done" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
[alert show];
```

}

I tried to add this code,
 alert.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,500,500);
but the text inside does not follow.

Is there any way to solve this? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change an UIAlertView :( It's deliberately designed to force you to be brief!

If you want to display a large amount of data, your best option is to create a custom UIView and show that instead.

Comment: Thanks. I was also wondering, seems I did not see any UIAlertView with different sizes.